# unity texture setting, usage of settexure()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am confused about the usage of GetTexture, SetTexture and .meinTexture.
I'm trying to work on applying a texture to a game object, but it doesn't work as expected.
To briefly explain the work now, I took coordinates, drew a mesh, turned the mesh into a game object, and applied colors with a material, and I am trying to implement a texture by applying different textures to the wall constructed in this way depending on the location.
It's obviously because I didn't understand it correctly, but the problem is that I don't know how to improve it.

```
nGO.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.shader = Shader.Find("TestTexture");
nGO.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = TestTexture;
nGO.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = Resources.Load(@"isaac.jpg") as Material;
nGO.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = Resources.Load(path) as Texture2D;
```

I tried the above methods and tried to use SetTexture as recommended, but,

```
nGO.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", Resources.Load("isaac.jpg", typeof(Texture)) as Texture);
```

I don't know what order to call. Is there any information that I can refer to, Can you provide some code for reference, even briefly? plz...

Comment: Let me get this clear, you want to apply (1) a Shader, (2) a "TestTexture" which I assume is a Texture2D, (3) an image "isaac.jpg" from the resources folder which should be loaded a Texture2D as well, and (4) yet another Texture2D loaded from the Resources folder with the name "path". Now the question is, how many materials does your MeshRenderer contain?

Comment: For testing purposes, there is currently only one "isaac.jpg".
The variety of loading methods is also the result of trying out different methods.
After all, "path" is the same role referring to "isaac.jpg".